# Localize UWP App

Tags: uwp

I have a Resource file in a folder Strings and with subfolders for the culture. See this image:

[image]

Also in appxmanifest I the default language is set to "en".
But unfortunaetly the language doesn't change with the system language.

Did I miss anything?

Link to repo: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyManager

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, adding this line of code to the OnLaunched Method in the App.cs solved thed problem:

```
        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];
```

Comment: Have you tried using "de-DE" and "en-US" instead? Also, in the `OnLaunched` method inside `App.xaml.cs`, try calling `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];` or enforce a specific language like `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";`. Maybe this helps?

Comment: I tried it with the "de-DE" and "en-US" but that didn't work. But calling the PrimaryLanguageOverride did the job. Thanks =)

Comment: can you share the resw file for any language? and have you provided fields with UID ?

Comment: the answer was already found in the first comment. I made an edit for it. But I guess it's easier to spot if I have a separat answer for it.
But thanks any way. (just for the record: the link to the repo is in the original question =))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, adding this line of code to the OnLaunched Method in the App.cs solved thed problem:

```
    ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're forcing the system language instead of following the user's language preferences?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you correctly, but from my perspective if the user has his computer on german the app should be in german. The exception would be if you override that with a setting in the app, which I currently don't offer.

Comment: See additional info in my old answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tied to the OS system language (language pack) but rather the User's preferred language:

- Start
- Settings
- Time & Language
- Region & Language
- Add a Language
- Set as Default

This will set the language preference for apps without affecting the language of the Windows Shell etc.

Windows has two concepts of Language -- the System Language, which is what the Start Menu, Explorer, and most Win32 apps use, and then the User Preferred Language List, which is what UWP apps use by default. In many cases, System Language == the only language in the UPLL because the user only cares about one language, but if they speak multiple languages then the UPLL can be quite useful. For example, say the user speaks French and Spanish, and their System language is French. Your app is defaulted to English, with a translation to Spanish. If you try and force it to the System language (French), the user will get English (which they don't understand). If you did nothing, they'd get Spanish (which they do understand).